# Create array of all regular expression matches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm attempting to use the [package match-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/match-all) to match CSS selectors and return an array of all of them.  This is the code.

```
const matchAll = require("match-all");

let s = `.u-br, .u-nr {
    blah blah
}

.u-tr {
    blah .blah
}`;
console.log(matchAll(s, /\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)/g).toArray());
```

When I run it it just logs `[]`, but the regex is correct [as can be seen here](https://regex101.com/r/BSefzJ/1).

Thoughts?  If the package has a bug, is there a simple work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/match-all) shows:

```
let s = "Hello _World_ and _Mars_";
console.log(matchAll(s, /_([a-z]+)_/gi).toArray());
// => [ "World", "Mars" ]
```

The resulting array is constructed from the *capturing groups*. This is what all their examples show. Presumably, if you don't have capturing groups, you could achieve the same thing using the built-in `.match`:

```js
let s = `.u-br, .u-nr {
    blah blah
}

.u-tr {
    blah .blah
}`;
console.log(s.match(/\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)/g));
```

So, if you want to use `match-all` for this, try enclosing the match in a capturing group:

```
matchAll(s, /(\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{))/g).toArray()
```